# How to add django model methods to a serialization?

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-models

**models.py**

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True)

    def fooFunc(self):
        return 'foo'
    foo = property(fooFunc)
```

**views.py**

```
def getCities(request):
    json = serialize('geojson', City.objects.all(), fields=('name', 'state', 'foo'))
    response = HttpResponse(json)
    return response
```

Whats happening in my views.py only returns the 'name' and 'state' fields in the json response. How can I get it to include the `foo` or the response of the method `fooFunc`?